# PowerShell Move Old Files with folder structure

Tags: file, powershell, move

I'm working with PowerShell and need to move all older files than x days to another folder, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $filepath -Recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(-$daystoarchive)} |
  Move-Item -destination $filearchivepath
```

But the problem is, that the folder structure is gone, when im adding "AddDays(-$daystoarchive)".

So how can i achieve this?

Comment: Use `-recurse` and `-container` with `Move-Item`. That preserves the structure.

Comment: You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Don't try to re-invent it in PowerShell unless you have a good reason to do so.